# I can't get the last group on Java Regex matches

Tags: java, regex

This is my String:

```
 Kết quả xổ số đài  Bình Phước ngày 05/01/2013 Tên Giải Bình Phước - Ký hiệu: bp-05-01 Giải tám 08 Giải bảy 028 Giải sáu 3137-1907-5049 Giải năm 2026 Giải tư 25982-96941-33495-24133-42882-60030-16818 Giải ba 15685-66788 Giải nhì 20283 Giải nhất 46475 Giải đặc biệt 207984
```

This is my pattern:

```
.*?(Giải tám([\\s\\d-]*?))?Giải bảy([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải sáu([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải năm([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải tư([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải ba([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải nhì([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải nhất([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải đặc biệt([\\s\\d]*?).*?
```

I try to get the 10 groups of numbers from the string. But I can't get the last group. It's always null. I also tested this http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and I got the same result, without last group.

Please tell me where my pattern wrong at.

UPDATE: the output has 10 group as below:

```
01-20 01:32:23.013: I/System.out(11368): group 0 : Kết quả xổ số đài  Bình Phước ngày 05/01/2013 Tên Giải Bình Phước - Ký hiệu: bp-05-01 Giải tám 08 Giải bảy 028 Giải sáu 3137-1907-5049 Giải năm 2026 Giải tư 25982-96941-33495-24133-42882-60030-16818 Giải ba 15685-66788 Giải nhì 20283 Giải nhất 46475 Giải đặc biệt 207984
01-20 01:32:23.013: I/System.out(11368): group 1 : Giải tám 08 
01-20 01:32:23.014: I/System.out(11368): group 2 :  08 
01-20 01:32:23.014: I/System.out(11368): group 3 :  028 
01-20 01:32:23.015: I/System.out(11368): group 4 :  3137-1907-5049 
01-20 01:32:23.015: I/System.out(11368): group 5 :  2026 
01-20 01:32:23.015: I/System.out(11368): group 6 :  25982-96941-33495-24133-42882-60030-16818 
01-20 01:32:23.015: I/System.out(11368): group 7 :  15685-66788 
01-20 01:32:23.016: I/System.out(11368): group 8 :  20283 
01-20 01:32:23.016: I/System.out(11368): group 9 :  46475 
01-20 01:32:23.017: I/System.out(11368): group 10 :
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see 11 _groups_ of numbers in your input string. Can you post the output you are trying to get from that input?

Comment: Please see my update. The matcher.groupCount() return 10, so I know that there are 10 groups found. You could copy the string and the pattern to test at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: `groupCount()` returns the number of groups in your regex, not the the number of groups matched in your input, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount())

Comment: Thank to Reimeus answer, I remove the last `?` at my last matching group and It works. But I don't understand why. Could you tell me why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `?` quantifer in your last matching group. Every wildcard expression is reluctant so will not consume all characters in the string. Having *at least* one greedy expression ensures that the last group can be matched.

```
.*?(Giải tám([\\s\\d-]*?))?Giải bảy([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải sáu([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải năm([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải tư([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải ba([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải nhì([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải nhất([\\s\\d-]*?)Giải đặc biệt([\\s\\d]*).*?
```

Comment: I remove the `?` at the last matching group and It works. But I don't understand why. Could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. Some time the pattern does not work. For example, this string return null when I call pattern.matcher(): `Kết quả xổ số đài  Đà Nẵng ngày 16/01/2013 Tên Giải Đà Nẵng - Ký hiệu: 16/01/2013 Giải tám 72 Giải bảy 539 Giải sáu 2539-0547-6344 Giải năm 7683 Giải tư 23848-57813-08826-84383-24408-72615-01193 Giải ba 08351-33404 Giải nhì 67609 Giải nhất 54217 Đặc biệt 281753`. I also test this with the online regex-test-tool (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). the tool return NO for matches() and find(). Help me please.

Comment: That string has `Đặc biệt` before the last matching group which is different from the string in the question, so the pattern won't match it.